# How to stop Netbeans from modifying a pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am contributing work to an open-source project that uses maven. I use Netbeans as my IDE.  Unfortunately, Netbeans has a habit of modifying the project's pom.xml file and adding dependencies on a plugin (selenium) not used by the project.   It does this without user consent. Is there a way to disable that feature?

Other information:

The version of Netbeans I am using is a bit old, 11.0, release 404.

This problem may be due to the way I set up the project.  I simply used the File->Open Project option, browsed over to the directory of interest and opened it up.

Comment: Hmm, I have never had NetBeans modify the pom without me initiating that

Comment: It must be an obscure problem since I didn't find anything related to it on stackoverflow or via Google.  I did use Netbeans to create some JUnit tests, but I stopped doing that because of the pom.xml issues.  Perhaps, in creating a unit test, I triggered some setting.

Comment: [1] Yes, it seems possible that you triggered something by creating those JUnit tests. But to be clear, is this is an open source project with no tests at all? [2] Is it possible to provide a link to the project so that others can download and attempt to reproduce the problem? Alternatively, can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? [3] It's trivial to prevent NetBeans updating pom.xml - just make the file read only - but that would presumably break the build, right?

Comment: I'm working on Apache commons-imaging and they have plenty of JUnit tests. When working on somebody else's project, I try to be a considerate guest. So you can see why modifying the pom.xml would be bad form.  I will try the readonly option.  That strike me as a pretty good idea.

Comment: I wish I could come up with a minimal reproducible example. Right now, I don't yet understand the sequence of events that leads to the problem. I was kinda hoping this was a known issue...  When I find something, I'll post more information.